# fooplugins/Footable - "Cannot read property 'name' of null" when trying to load the table from JSON

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, ajax, footable

I want to use the plugin "FooTable" with ajax calls.
Everything works fine when I hardcode the JSON, or even load it from a JSON file with $.get('....json'). When I try to load the table content from my server, I always get the error message "Cannot read property 'name' of null" shown with details here:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LPvk.png)

The image above also shows the JSON logged into the Console. I've tried loading it in a lot of different ways (in back- and front-end), but I just cant get it to work. I left some of my tries commented out in the attached Code.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
jQuery(function ($) {
    var ft = FooTable.init('.table', {
        "columns": $.get('/js/mycols.json'),
        //"rows": $.get('/js/myrows.json')
        "rows": $.get('/api/GetEvents', function (e) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(e.value));
            //ft.rows.load(JSON.parse(e.value));
        }, "json")
    });
    //$.ajax({
    //    url: "/api/GetEvents",
    //    dataType: "json",
    //    type: "GET"
    //}).done(function (e) {
    //    console.log(e);
    //    ft.rows.load(e.value);
    //})             
  });
});
```

ASP.NET Backend:

```
List<JObject> objList = new List<JObject>();
foreach (var e in events)
{
    JObject jObj = JObject.FromObject(new
    {
        name = e.Name,
        veranstaltungstyp = e.Type,
        startzeit = e.StartTime.ToString("H:mm - dd MMMM yyyy"),
        ende = e.EndTime.ToString("H:mm - dd MMMM yyyy"),
        erstelltvon = e.CreatedBy.FirstName + " " + e.CreatedBy.LastName,
        render = "placeholder"
    });

    objList.Add(jObj);
}
var result = new JsonResult(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objList));
result.ContentType = "json";
result.StatusCode = 200;
result.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerOptions();
return Json(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  It appears that FooTable is trying to load the rows before the table has been fully rendered and so it is not able to properly access the DOM.

Try wrapping your fetch in a on('ready.ft.table').

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
jQuery(function ($) {
    var ft = FooTable.init('.table', {
        "columns": $.get('/js/mycols.json'),
    });
    $('.table').on('ready.ft.table', function(e) {
      $.ajax({
          url: "/api/GetEvents",
          dataType: "json",
          type: "GET"
      }).done(function (e) {
          console.log(e);
          ft.rows.load(e.value);
      })             
    });
  });
});
```